# Getting Error While Installing Heroku Toolbelt on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am Trying to install Heroku on Ubuntu i am getting following error and while installing i am getting error please check i am new to rails project

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
 This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
 You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
 [sudo] password for giri: 
 --2016-04-11 23:56:12--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
  Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 23.21.68.222,       23.23.160.223, 107.20.233.51
 Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com   (toolbelt.heroku.com)|23.21.68.222|:443... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 1737 (1.7K) [application/octet-stream]
 Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

 100%[======================================>] 1,737       --.-K/s   in 0s      
 2016-04-11 23:56:14 (148 MB/s) - written to stdout [1737/1737]

  OK
     Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
     Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
    Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_IN                            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  heroku
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  heroku heroku-toolbelt
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 678 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,828 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package heroku.
(Reading database ... 211926 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../heroku_3.42.50_all.deb ...
Unpacking heroku (3.42.50) ...
Selecting previously unselected package heroku-toolbelt.
Preparing to unpack .../heroku-toolbelt_3.42.50_all.deb ...
Unpacking heroku-toolbelt (3.42.50) ...
Setting up heroku (3.42.50) ...
Setting up heroku-toolbelt (3.42.50) ...
```

After installation get check version i get error like this

```
 giri@giri:~$ heroku -v
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    Command:     heroku -v
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.42.50 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
    Error ID:    59e2f7f1adc64081af2a4ab6a95becdb


    More information in /home/giri/.heroku/error.log
```

Comment: so what does the error log say?

Comment: Try heroku --version instead of -v

Comment: 2016/02/08 14:40:55 heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
2016/02/08 14:42:18  done
2016/02/08 14:42:18 heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
2016/02/08 14:44:26  done
2016/02/08 14:44:26 Email:@Heroku client internal error.
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @apesa ,sir still i am getting same error

Answer (score 1):

@user5065277 try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202451/fetching-error-when-installing-heroku)  "The mirror in your software sources might not be up-to-date"(...)